# How do i restart my eclipse

Tags: eclipse, automation

I am trying to write a script for my eclipse updatesite. I am updating all my plugins to plugins folder and feature to features folder to their latest versions available using a pom.xml file.

Now my requirement is, i want to add a eclipse restart command to prompt for the user input with "Restart Now" "Restart later" buttons like we see in regular eclipse update site work flow.

Can anyone provide me some inputs for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```java
 Display display = Display.getDefault();

    if (display != null) {
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(),
                        "Dialog title"
                        null, "Restart eclipse?"
                        MessageDialog.QUESTION, new String[] { "OK","Restart Later" }
                        0);
                if (dialog.open() == 0) {
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chandrayya for your inputs. i have no knowledge in java. Can you provide this resolution either in batch commands or in ant script?

It would be great if these commands can be run with in my pom file.

Comment: In case of multiple eclipse installation how do you decide which instance to restart.If you are installing a plugin through maven task then how your are detecting how many eclipse instances are running and where you are currently installing the plugin i. to which location? and how you are checking whether an eclipse is opened from that location?. If it so it becomes question on maven.Re tag your question appropriately.Show your maven pom file edit your question and write what are you expecting.

Comment: My plan is to give a eclipse as a zip file, where the zip contains bat file to run two tasks.

One is to run mvn clean install

Second is the command to restart the eclipse.

User just need to double click on the bat file to be run, so that it will automatically update all plugins/features in its parent directory location.